# Уведомления приходят много раз (VkNet)

Tags: c#, .net, vknet

У меня есть приложение для группы вк с открытыми сообщениями. Проблема такова: у меня есть бесконечный цикл, в котором я проверяю обновления (poll.Updates), и если они есть, ищу сообщения, и отвечаю на них. После ответа я обнуляю обновления. Но в каждом прогоне цикла сообщается о том же сообщении. А если придет еще одно сообщение, то в каждом действии цикла сообщается о обоих сообщениях. Мне надо обнулить все обновления после ответа на сообщение, но этого не происходит.

```
while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var poll = api.Groups.GetBotsLongPollHistory(
                        new BotsLongPollHistoryParams()
                        { Server = s.Server, Ts = s.Ts, Key = s.Key, Wait = 1 });

                if (poll?.Updates == null) continue; //если обновлений нет, ждём
                foreach (var a in poll.Updates) //если есть, ищем среди них сообщение
                {
                    if (a.Type == GroupUpdateType.MessageNew)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(a.Message.Text); //выводим его в консоль
                        api.Messages.Send(new MessagesSendParams //и отправляем текст этого сообщения пользователю
                        {
                            PeerId = a.Message.PeerId,
                            RandomId = new Random().Next(1, 1000000000),
                            Message = a.Message.Text
                        });
                        Console.WriteLine("Sended");
                        poll.Updates = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо просто изменять время, с которого надо получать события. Для этого в цикл while перед foreach поставьте `s.Ts = pool.Ts;`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.